# How to input unicode character and get its numeric value

Tags: python

I am trying to take a file and remove all characters that are not in the greek language. We found the unicode values for the alphabet, 880 - 1023, and were able to print out the correct characters with a simple `print(unichr(880))` line. The problem is when running this code

```
greek ='ÏÎ' 
for c in greek:
    if(unichr(c) >= 880 and unichr(c) <= 1023):
        print(c)
```

Is there a way to enter any letter or symbol that will return a unicode value. We have tested with values inside of the greek range and outside and still get the same error, `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec cannot decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: I think you want `ord`

Comment: yes, `unichr` is just `chr` in python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems. Assuming this is python 2 (since there is no `unichr` in python 3 you'd get a different error) your first problem is that you didn't initialize a unicode string in the first place.

```
>>> greek ='ÏÎ' 
>>> len(greek)
4
```

These aren't 2 unicode characters... they are 4 single byte characters that also happen to be the utf-8 encodings of the unicode characters. Instead do

```
greek =u'ÏÎ'
```

Next, these are not the droids, I mean greek characters, you think they are.

```
>>> ord(greek[0])
207
```

These are codepage characters in the 128-255 range and are outside of the range you are looking for. Did you want these instead?

```
>>> greek = u'Ϊΐ'
>>> ord(greek[0])
938
```

Finally, `unichr` goes the wrong way... it converts ordinals to characters but you wanted to go the other way. So,

```
>>> for c in greek:
...     if ord(c) >= 880 and ord(c) <= 1023:
...         print(c)
... 
Ϊ
ΐ
```

Comment: is there a site/link that gave you the correct symbols/letters and codes associated with them. do we do the same thing if we read this off a file. Our end goal is to read a large file and we are getting the logic and testing on a few characters first

Comment: The odd conversion could have happened in several places so its possible that you had the right numbers to start with. Its one of the 100 ways unicode drives me crazy. I used [unicode test page](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html) (you need to remove spaces) but `u''.join(unichr(x) for x in range(880, 1024))` would work.

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend implementing in python 3 if you can. Its default string type is unicode and there are fewer surprises. Sometimes its more confusing at first because you may juggle bytes, encodings and etc... but there are fewer mistakes all in all.

Answer (score 2):

`unichr` accepts an integer and *returns* a unicode character. My first suggestion is that you replace `unichr` with `ord` here, since you're passing in a string and want to get back an integer that represents a unicode code point.

Now for the Unicode decode errror—I suspect that it's occurring because `print` is implicitly trying to encode your unicode string, but doesn't know how to do so. You might have more luck if you explicitly encode your unicode string with utf-8. Try this:

```
greek = u'ÏÎ' 
for c in greek:
    if(ord(c) >= 880 and ord(c) <= 1023):
        print(c.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use `ord`, it is like the inverse function of `chr` or `unichr`:

```
>>> x = unichr(1000)
>>> ord(x)
1000
>>> y = unichr(880)
>>> y
u'\u0370'
>>> ord(y)
880
>>> help(ord)
Help on built-in function ord in module __builtin__:

ord(...)
    ord(c) -> integer

    Return the integer ordinal of a one-character string.
```

so you pass it a unicode character and it gives you the ordinal of the character.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure your editor saves your program in UTF-8 encoding. This depends on the text editor you use.  If you use IDLE, it will suggest to add the `coding` line when you save.

Also, no need to enclose conditions in parentheses, and you can use short .

This is for python 3

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
greek ='ÏÎ' 
for c in greek:
  if 880 <= ord(c) <= 1023:
    print(c)
```

(In my screen, the two characters appear as capital I with tilde accent and capital I with circumflex accent--replace with appropriate characters).